# Using composite PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE key on INNODB table with multiple inserts

Tags: sql, performance, insert, indexing, innodb

I have been trying to figure this out, but no luck so far.

Which one is better: A table with a composite PRIMARY KEY OR a single PRIMARY KEY and a UNIQUE index?

My table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE data (
  bucket_id INTEGER,
  backend_id INTEGER,
  unique_id INTEGER,
  weight INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY (bucket_id, unique_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

I am doing multiple inserts. 6 billion+ rows to be inserted in multi value inserts in the form of

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO data VALUES (x1, x2, x3, x4), (y1, y2, y3, y4), .......)
```

with 500000 rows in each (limited by the client). These are all done on startup of the application and currently I need to speed this up as much as possible. I need the uniqueness of (backend_id, unique_id). Though I do not control these so there are duplicates in the imported data.

So the question is, will using a UNIQUE index instead of a composite PRIMARY KEY help me to increase speed of the insert statements? I know a lot of other factors affect this i.e. buffer pools and so on.

Comment: *"Which one is better: A table with a composite PRIMARY KEY OR a single PRIMARY KEY and a UNIQUE index?"* What would the "single primary key" be?

Comment: *" I need the uniqueness of (backend_id, unique_id). Though I do not control these so there are duplicates in the imported data."* Does that mean there's bad data that you need to fix or ignore?

Comment: The singe PRIMARY KEY would be bucket_id. No the data is not bad, but the uniqueness of the data relies on more columns that I need to import, so if two rows collide then backend_id and weight will be the same, so it's safe to ignore the second row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that primary key constraints in all modern database management systems are implemented using unique indexes. In SQL the declarations `PRIMARY KEY` and `NOT NULL UNIQUE` are behaviorally equivalent.

Your question boils down to this: is it faster to use a surrogate key *in addition* to the requisite constraint on {backend_id, unique_id}? Note carefully that using a surrogate key *instead* of the requisite constraint on {backend_id, unique_id} isn't generally acceptable, because it omits an important business requirement.

Adding a surrogate key

- makes the table wider,
- increases the number of bytes that have to be written to the table, and
- increases the number of indexes that have to be written.

So adding a surrogate key will probably slow you down.  This is probably the best structure for your stated requirements *if you require concurrent access*.

```
CREATE TABLE data (
  backend_id INTEGER,
  unique_id INTEGER,
  weight INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY (backend_id, unique_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

But if you can essentially run in single-user mode, it's fastest to load a table with *no* constraints, using the bulk loader.  Then add the constraints later with `ALTER TABLE` statements.

Comment: Sorry if I am not being clear, I apologize. But the questions is not about the SQL syntax, but whether the latter suggestion is faster, when doing a lot of inserts.